# Getting error when loading tab-delimited files from gcs to Bigquery in a python script

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using a Python script to load files from GCS to Bigquery.  It works when loading comma separated file which is the default.  However, when trying to load a tab-delimited file after setting the following job properties:

```
  job.allowQuotedNewlines=True
  job.fieldDelimiter='\t'
  job.skipLeadingRows=1
  job.maxBadRecords=9999999
```

The job is inserted by:

```
 job.begin()
```

It gives the following error:

```
   "errors": [
   {
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Too many errors encountered."
   },
   {
    "reason": "invalid",
    "location": "gs://my-test/test-file",
    "message": "CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 columns."
```

}

Is it still looking for comma delimiter? It looks like none of the properties that was set in the script was actually taken by the API. 
What am I missing?

Here are 2 lines from the file I am trying to load:

```
0265cd91-3126-4f54-a7e3-54be3ef2d8f9    357215cb-c073-4e67-bfdb-7085f8709015    398a9017-1157-4891-aacb-8108c5fb6378    6bb1f59a-81bb-49da-9974-193a23cb3bca    test B  test2 B 0   2017-03-21 18:48:32 2017-03-21 18:48:32
02aa9715-e47b-4cd9-89f8-a091f7a6e81d    1186dfc3-3b2f-456a-be06-bf5f5a0f7c12    398a9017-1157-4891-aacb-8108c5fb6378    e1983ef2-d7a1-49ce-9fe2-a5cd439b8ca0    test A  test2 A 0   2017-06-26 14:37:43 2017-06-26 14:37:43
```

Here are the same 2 lines after "set list" in vim.  As you can see the separators are "^I":

```
  0265cd91-3126-4f54-a7e3-54be3ef2d8f9^I357215cb-c073-4e67-bfdb-7085f8709015^I398a9017-1157-4891-aacb-8108c5fb6378^I6bb1f59a-81bb-49da-9974-193a23cb3bca^IRockMedium B^IRockMedium
  02aa9715-e47b-4cd9-89f8-a091f7a6e81d^I1186dfc3-3b2f-456a-be06-bf5f5a0f7c12^I398a9017-1157-4891-aacb-8108c5fb6378^Ie1983ef2-d7a1-49ce-9fe2-a5cd439b8ca0^IStairModule A^IStairModu
```

Here is complete code:

```
  dest_dataset = "temp"
  dest_table = "lineItems_copy"
  destination = self.bq_client.dataset(dest_dataset).table(name=dest_table)
  source_files = "gs://my-test/test-*"
  job_id = "load_gcs_file_to_bq_" +  str(uuid.uuid4())
  print ("job_id= ", job_id)
  job = self.bq_client.load_table_from_storage(job_id, destination, source_files)
  job_properties = {'createDisposition': 'CREATE_NEVER', 'sourceFormat': 'CSV', 'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_APPEND'}

  #testing with tab-delimited:
  job.allowQuotedNewlines=True
  job.fieldDelimiter='\t'
  job.skipLeadingRows=1
  job.maxBadRecords=9999999
  submit_async_load_job(self.bq_client, self.cloud_logger, job, job_id, job_properties)

def submit_async_load_job(bq_client, logger, job, job_id, load_job_options): 
   for key, value in load_job_options.iteritems():
     print ("key value: " , key, " ", value)
     set_property = 'job.' + key + '="'+value+'"'
     print set_property
     exec(set_property)            
   job.begin()
   wait_for_job(logger, job, job_id)
   return
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you show us just one line of your file as a sample for us to analyze?

Comment: can you post your complete code?

Comment: just added sample data and the entire code.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: the 2 lines pasted don't contain a tab - therefore tab is not a separator, or we are trying to debug the wrong file

Comment: They are tab-delim.  I downloaded the file and opened it in Vim and set list, the speparators show up as "^I"  which I understand is the representation of tab

Comment: I just added the same two lines from the file to be loaded after doing "set list" in vim to show the lines after showing hidden chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the property names:  When submiting the load job with this API, the properties are spelled differently, for ex.:  job.fieldDelimiter='\t'  should be

```
 job.field_delimiter='\t'
```